# How to color numbers in certain parts of a lstlisting

Tags: listings, color, xml

So, I'm a student and my teacher posted this kind of "how to make XML look cool in LaTeX". We were using it in class but I noticed some errors.

For example, when printing numbers inside the labels (as in `<number> this is 25 </number>`) the program won't print the number 25 the same color as the rest of the words.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

I'd like them printed in the same way that the rest of the text.
I tried telling LaTeX to print all the numbers red, but that works too for the XML declaration. Which is not nice.

There's any way to do what I'm asking for?

---

Thanks for the help, I'm a total noob :D

Sorry for the bad english <3

The actual code:

```
\documentclass[11.5pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  morestring=[b]",
  moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{<}{\ },
  moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{</}{>},
  moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{/>},
  moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{>},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  numberstyle=\color{red}
  morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
  commentstyle=\color{DarkOliveGreen},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{red},
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
  {á}{{\textcolor{red}{\'a}}}{1} 
  {é}{{\textcolor{red}{\'e}}}{1} 
  {í}{{\textcolor{red}{\'i}}}{1} 
  {ó}{{\textcolor{red}{\'o}}}{1} 
  {ú}{{\textcolor{red}{\'u}}}{1} 
  {ñ}{{\textcolor{red}{\"n}}}{1}, 
}


\begin{document}
\lstset{language=XML}
\begin{lstlisting}
<number> This is 25</number>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.